# detecting 0 in the end of the IP, last octate / bash

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to write a filter bash script
which will detect IP with 0 in the end and will filter it"

```
    #!/bin/bash
file="ip.list"
while read i
do
ldi=`echo "$i" | cut -d"." -f4`
if [ ! $ldi -eq 0 ]; then
 echo $i >> no0ip.list
else
 echo -e "$i Zero IP removed"
fi
done < $file
```

it does work, but do not feel that it is the best way to do...

What would be the shortest and more efficient way to achieve the same effect ?

**Update**

Fragment of the IP list

```
100.43.91.0
100.43.91.249
100.43.0.250
100.43.91.251
100.43.0.252
100.43.91.253
100.43.91.254
100.43.91.255
199.21.99.0
199.21.99.1
199.0.99.2
199.21.99.3
199.21.99.4
```

We need to filter only the ones with the last Octate=0

Comment: `gawk -F. '$4!="0"' ip.list` should produce addresses which don't end with "0" after the last dot...

Comment: can you show the fragment of `ip.list`?

Comment: `grep "\.0$"` - something more?

Answer (score 1):

One `grep` is enough:

```
grep -v '\.0$' ip.list > no0ip.list
```

Comment: for double conditions it'll be: grep -v '\.0$ | \.255$'  ip.list > no0ip.list   ?